# Binding two Perl hashes (not two anonymous hashes)

Tags: perl, hash

In order to reuse some already written code libraries, I need to "masquerade" a hash (`%bar`) into another hash (`%foo`) so that each changes made in `%bar` can be seen with `%foo` *after* their binding.

With an anonymous hash construct, it's easy: just copy the ref of `bar` into the ref of `foo`  ( `$foo = $bar;` ).

How about "not using" an anonymous hash (because the code I have to reuse is built not using anonymous hash constructs) ?  Is this only possible ?

Thanks.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my  %foo = ();
my  %bar = ();

%foo = %bar;    # This won't work as it copies %bar into %foo as at the current time.

$bar{A}->{st} = 'a';
$bar{A}->{qt} = 'a';
$bar{B}->{st} = 'b';
$bar{B}->{qt} = 'b';

# $foo{A}->{st}  doesn't exist
```

Of course, an anonymous hash construct would have been a blessing.

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my  $foo = {};
my  $bar = {};

$foo = $bar;   # This works fine.

$bar->{A}->{st} = 'a';
$bar->{A}->{qt} = 'a';
$bar->{B}->{st} = 'b';
$bar->{B}->{qt} = 'b';

print STDOUT "foo\n---\n";
print Dumper($foo) . "\n\n";

print STDOUT "bar\n---\n";
print Dumper($bar) . "\n\n";
```

Yields the expected result:

```
foo
---
$VAR1 = {
          'B' => {
                   'st' => 'b',
                   'qt' => 'b'
                 },
          'A' => {
                   'qt' => 'a',
                   'st' => 'a'
                 }
        };


bar
---
$VAR1 = {
          'B' => {
                   'st' => 'b',
                   'qt' => 'b'
                 },
          'A' => {
                   'qt' => 'a',
                   'st' => 'a'
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that exactly? Sounds like you're making your life hard. What's the overall intent?

Comment: As I wrote, I have to reuse an existing library that I'm not allowed to modify, mapping new content (my content) to an existing hash (not mine) which then will be processed by this library. If it were only for me, I wouldn't have bothered. Thus, I'de like to understand if the language allows `%foo=();` to be replaced by another existing constructor. Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase it maybe? There is code that creates a hash variable. Is that lexical or global? Is it in a package? Is it the return value of a function call?

Comment: No, bunch of (quite) independent files put together with "`require()`". I'm modifying one of them that will create the `%bar` content. I can negotiate adding one line to create "_bar linked to foo_". If I were allowed to modify the existing code, I'll turn it all to anon-hash in a jiffy.
In general - not talking about my (poor) case - is it possible to substitute the constructor created by `%bar=();` by another ?

Comment: Note: That code needs to be extremely fast in execution (< tenth of a sec), therefore it loads portions of codes it needs with selective `require()`

Comment: Actually that doesn't make it faster, because it makes the Perl compiler switch between compile time and run time. Legacy is fun.

Comment: There is no constructor in `%bar = ()`. `%bar` is just a hash, not an object. You are _initializing_ it with the empty list (if it didn't have a value before). And with `my %bar` you are _declaring_ it. If there was a constructor, you could overwrite that by either sub-classing or monkey-patching into your package. But you don't have packages it seems, so that's not possible. What you can do to avoid further confusion is write new code in packages and start slowly moving away from the legacy stuff. When you need to work with it, also put it in a package. `package legacy { require 'foo.pl' }`

Answer (score 5):

For your example, you can use [Data::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) to alias `%bar` to `%foo`. That allows you to make changes in `%bar` and later see those in `%foo`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use Data::Alias;

my  %foo = ();
my  %bar = ();

alias %foo = %bar;

$bar{A}->{st} = 'a';
$bar{A}->{qt} = 'a';
$bar{B}->{st} = 'b';
$bar{B}->{qt} = 'b';

p %foo;
p %bar;
```

**Output:**

```
{
    A   {
        qt   "a",
        st   "a"
    },
    B   {
        qt   "b",
        st   "b"
    }
}
{
    A   {
        qt   "a",
        st   "a"
    },
    B   {
        qt   "b",
        st   "b"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, it means that the language doesn't allow for it, thus requiring resorting to using a external code. Did I read somewhere that Data:Alias is manipulating Perl internal data structures to achieve this feat ? Thus leading with some uncertainty to some upward compatibility issues. This won't fit with the customer.
I presume that I'll have to file for rewriting these external files I was mentioning (and trigger some complex re-validation process). Here goes our life. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: I believe it does. A look at the source reveals 2k lines of nice XS code. But you cannot really know if it does anything upstream. You could have tests, but I guess you don't have those for that project. Using CPAN on the other hand should not be put asside. It's a valuable asset and one of the strong points that Perl has over newer technologies today.